# Read linked list backwards without changing it

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

Given a singly linked list read the list backwards. It sounds like an easy question but(!) you can't change the pointers of the linked list, you can only use 3 variables (pointers or other vars), each cell has a bool flag that starts with false, you can use that as you want.

It's easy to do it in O(n^2) but I think there is a better solution (maybe O(n)?).

Comment: But why?  Is this an academic exercise?

Comment: Use a stack: push all list elements on it, then you can pull 'em off in reverse order. That would be `O(n)`

Comment: you can solve it recursively... you start at the head, make a call to next (recursively) until you are at tail or nullptr... then the recursion gets closed, there you can print out the value... it is than O(n) so in linear time

Comment: yes it is, but its also useful because pointers are heavy and it's difficult for the computer to change their values

Comment: Isn't stack and recursive approach the same? But OPs question is using only 3 external variables and both these use at least N external variables

Comment: @OferMagen what have you tried so far? This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 2):

This recursive method works with only 1 time iterating over the list. So it is O(n).

**how does it work:**

It goes recursive through the list until it is at the end and adds a methodcall onto the stackframe. At the end it prints out the last node and returns to the 2nd last method call (it goes backwarts through the stackframe)

```
void RecursiveBackwardPrint(node* node)
{
    if(node->next != nullptr)
    {
        RecursiveBackwardPrint(node->next);
    }
    std::cout<<node->value<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @Ofer Magen: Is this what you expected? Or did I understood the question wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in O(n) by combining each time 32 booleans in order to convert them to a pointer to the previous block of 32 elements.

Algorithm:

- Read last elements of list in order to make list size % 32. (O(n*32) = O(n))
- Use booleans in elements 32 to 63 to store a pointer to the beginning, booleans in elements 64 to 95 to store a pointer to element 32, and so on (O(n))
- Go to last 32 blocks (O(n)), read them (O(32)), jump back to last 64 blocks (O(1)), read the next 32 blocks in backwards order (O(32)), jump back to last 96 blocks and so on.

It's O(n) but takes at least 32*n operations, it's only worth it for very long lists.